# Deploy GitHub Pages site at mysite.com/<subdirectory>

Tags: git, github, github-pages, web-hosting

I plan on hosting project sites using GitHub Pages and using my domain for them, so that they look something like this:

```
mysite.com/projects/<project>
```

From what I can see, GitHub provides no documentation for that. It only supports apex and subdomains.

Scouring the Internet showed me people trying to set a subdirectory *in GitHub* to their apex domain -- which, again, is not what I'm looking for.

I suppose I could route `<sub>.mysite.com` to a directory through DNS, since I have a practically non-existent limit of 250 subdomains, but that's an ugly hack.

Comment: It would be just a folder in the repo, right? What documentation are you expecting?

Comment: Say one repository leads to /projects/foo, another repository leads to /projects/bar, and the apex domain leads to yet another static site. GitHub doesn't allow multiple repos to use the same domain, afaik

Comment: Are you going to put your repos onto the web to be accessed without any security?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand the question. I'm using Cloudflare, if that's what you're asking. I don't plan to route the GitHub repo itself to my domain, only the site located on the gh-pages branch.

Comment: Having `/projects/foo` and `/projects/bar` is possible. They will be folders inside of the `gh-pages` repo. The reason I asked about exposing the repos is because you mentioned having multiple repos in the gh-pages repo. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You're talking about hosting all of the project *sites* together, separated from their respective code repos, which is a solution I hadn't thought of, but what I mean is

on GH repo `foo` there's master and gh-pages;
on GH repo `bar` there's master and gh-pages;
and so on -- with all the pages being tied under the same domain